# Why doesn't the default bash_completion code in .bashrc work?

Tags: bash, alias, bash-completion

When I run terminal and type `Tab` after entering the beginning of a command, nothing pops up. However, after running `. /etc/bash_completion` in that terminal, I get completion suggestions.

The following code segment is in my `.bashrc` file:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

[Online](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/bash-completion-complete/), I see information about this code segment is actually what should be activating bash_completion.

My question is, what is the process that I take to ensure that everything necessary is set up for this to perform properly?

**Code reference update:**

```
$ cat ~/.profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: what OS are you using, MacOS or a linux distro?

Comment: Linux Mint O-p-e-r-a-t-i-n-g S-y-s-t-e-m